# Rails - ActiveRecord query - Find first item where relationship.count at least 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I'm attempting to find the most recent Post that has at least one Comment.

I tried this:

```
@post = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT *, count(comment.id) AS num_of_comments
  FROM post
  INNER JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id
  WHERE num_of_comments >= 1").last
```

but got an error saying num_of_comments was an unknown column.

Then I tried a method on Post, but that didn't work:

```
def self.has_been_commented
  where("comments.count <= 1")
end
```

I then started looking into scopes, and saw the .joins method, but wasn't sure how I could then specify another filter.
Something like:

```
scope :has_been_commented, joins(:comments)
```

but then I'm not sure how to specify where(:comments.count >= 1)

Sorry if that is confusing...

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I can't test it, but what about: `Post.joins(:comments).having('count(comments.id) > 1')`

Comment: I'm getting unknown column 'comments.id'

Comment: The generated SQL is:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'comments.id' in 'having clause': SELECT `post`.* FROM `post` INNER JOIN `comment` ON `comment`.`post_id` = `post`.`id` HAVING count(comments.id) > 1
It all looks good up to the HAVING section

Comment: `Post.joins(:comments).having("count(*) > 1")` should do what you want. You can then play with order clauses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

```
Post.find(:all, :joins => "INNER JOIN comment ON comment.post_id = post.id", .
  :select => "post.*, count(comment.id) comment_count", 
  :group => "comment.post_id HAVING comment_count >= 1").last
```

Answer (score 0):

You have plural `comments` and singular `comment` liberally mixed together. If you are following "the Rails way" then everything would be plural, even the database name, *except* your class name. The goal is to make sure the SQL being generated matches the database table you have.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately I inherited this project, and the creator had used singular table names.  I did have a copy/paste formatting error in that SQL though having plurality.  Changing my Model names for fun?